# Open usercontrol at runtime-WPF?

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application, I have a table which stores the frequently used window names for each user. At runtiime, I make a list of it.

```
List<string> LstUserWindows= new List<string>();
```

What I need is I need to open each window depending on the names of the windows in the list. (I am using usercontrols as windows). Something like below:

```
 foreach (var rec in LstUserWindows)
 {
      UserControl mainUC = this.FindName(rec.MyWindow) as UserControl;
      displayUserControls(mainUC,null); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which approach you have currently taken in storing the `UserControl` instances, but here are two possible approaches you could take.

1. If all `UserControl` instances already exist within your UI but are simply hidden, then you should be able to use the `FindName(...)` (as you've mentioned in your question) and then change the `Visibility` property of the `UserControl`.
2. If you have not yet loaded the `UserControl` instances and you want to dynamically create the control given it's name, then you need to look into using [Reflection](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257). Using this approach, you can acquire the `Type` information from the `Assembly` and work on using Reflection to construct the object. Alternately, you could use the [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to construct an instance of the required control type. For that approach, you would do something like this.

   ```
   foreach (var rec in LstUserWindows)
   {
       UserControl control = (UserControl)System.Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", rec);
       displayUserControls(control, null);
   }
   ```

Note: I'm not sure if the parameter structure is correct (I cannot currently test it). Check out the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31f93hw6.aspx) for more help on it.